# Why does untriggered assignment changed `nonlocal` behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-nonlocal

Today I'm reading python change log and meet the nonlocal keyword and did some experiment with it. I find a confusing situation where untriggered assignment will change the `nonlocal` keyword behavior, please see the example below.

```
def a():
    x = 'a'
    def b():
        def c():
            nonlocal x
            x = 'c'
        c()
    b()
    print(x)

a()

>>> python3 test.py
c


def a():
    x = 'a'
    def b():
        def c():
            nonlocal x
            x = 'c'
        c()
        if False:
            x = 'b'
    b()
    print(x)

a()

>>> python3 test2.py
a
```

You can saw that in `test2.py`, there is an untriggered assginment `x = 'b'` which changed the behavior of nonlocal.

Why this happened?

Comment: Assignment statements always make a variable *local* unless you use `global` or `nonlocal`, it doesn't matter if the assignment is inaccesible at rutime. This happens at *compile time*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I know that, but I mean, by my understanding, when python interpreter reads `if False` and find out condition not satisfied, it won't execute the `x = 'b'` statement, then how would an not executed assignment influenced the nonlocal keyword?

Comment: because it happens at *compile time*, the runtime behavior is irrelevant. Read the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Python decides which variables are local to a function *at compile time*. `x` is assigned to within the function `b`, so it's local. That that branch is never actually reached at runtime is irrelevant and can't be decided in general.

So the `x` in `c` that is nonlocal is the next `x` in an outer scope, namely the one in `b`.

The alternative would be much more surprising -- consider what would happen if the `if False:` was instead `if rand(10) == 6:`. Then during the first call of `b` the nonlocal variable would refer to the outermost one, but randomly at some later call of `b` it would start referring to the other one!